# RestRequest Create Custom Object

Tags: rest-api, sandbox, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I'm using the android salesforce SDK. I am connecting to a sandbox and am trying to create a custom object, however I keep getting a 404 error:

```
( 4097): [241] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://acumensolutions--AcumenFull.cs13.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/CSR_Participant
D/ERROR   ( 4097): [{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]
```

I'm assuming it can't find my sandbox? Why is that though? I can sign in just find and get an access token. Here's my request:

```
    request = RestRequest.getRequestForCreate(apiVersion, "CSR_Participant",
                        fields);
/**
     * Sends a REST request using RestClient's sendAsync method.
     * Note: Synchronous calls are not allowed from code running on the UI thread.
     *
     * @param restRequest REST request.
     */
    private void sendFromUIThread(RestRequest restRequest) {
        client.sendAsync(restRequest, new RestClient.AsyncRequestCallback() {
            private long start = System.nanoTime();

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, RestResponse result) {
                try {
                    long duration = System.nanoTime() - start;
                    println(result);
                    int size = result.asString().length();
                    int statusCode = result.getStatusCode();
                    printRequestInfo(duration, size, statusCode);
                    extractIdsFromResponse(result.asString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    printException(e);
                }

                EventsObservable.get().notifyEvent(EventType.RenditionComplete);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception exception) {
                printException(exception);
                EventsObservable.get().notifyEvent(EventType.RenditionComplete);

                VolleyError volleyError = (VolleyError) exception;
                NetworkResponse response = volleyError.networkResponse;
                String json = new String(response.data);
                Log.d("ERROR", json);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you've missed the `__c` from your object name. Try `https://acumensolutions--AcumenFull.cs13.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/CSR_Participant__c`

Comment: I've tried that as well. I get a this error when I type it into chrome:

<Errors>
<Error>
<errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode>
<message>Session expired or invalid</message>
</Error>
</Errors>

Comment: You need to authenticate with Salesforce before you can use the REST API, the REST API documentation covers how to do this and obtain an access token using OAuth, the user-password flow is the easiest to get started with but may not be the best choice long term https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_authentication.htm

Comment: I get the same error when I try in code as well

Comment: I found this in the sample test project:

SalesforceSDKManager.initNative(getApplicationContext(), new KeyImpl(), MainActivity.class);

Can I not use that to authenticate?

Comment: Page 85 of the [Mobile SDK Developer Guide](https://bitly.com/1vwq1rL) should cover what you need

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a new Custom Object using REST API. New custom objects can only be created using Metadata API.

The API you are referring is used to create a new record of said object (be it Custom or Standard). See [this](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_sobject_basic_info.htm) for more information about the api, specifically `For an example of creating a new record using POST, see Create a Record.`